# Formulario Contato HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html, formulário

olá, Bom estou tentando fazer um formulario de contato SMTP funcionar, porem esta me retornando erro
`PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $msg in .../..././././././index.php on line 119`
porem a algum tempo atras(2/3 semanas) estava funcionando perfeitamente. estava em pastas na hospedagem em teste(pastas aleatorias) mudei para a pasta principal no caso a (public_html) e deixou de funcionando me retornando este erro.

HTML

```
<?php include_once "enviar.php"; ?>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="formuh1">Formulario de Contato.</h1>
<!--la propiedad enctype permite el envío de archivos adjuntos en el formulario. -->
    <form id="form1" class="form-horizontal well col-lg" action="index.php#formulario" method="post" name="form1" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Nome:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" value="" placeholder="seu nome" required >
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">      
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="contato@visaomater" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div> 
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">  
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Telefone*:</label>  
                <div class="col-sm-9">       
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="(62) 3284-0047" onkeypress="mask(this, telefone);" onblur="mask(this, telefone);" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>  
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">    
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Assunto*:</label> 
                <div class="col-sm-9">      
                    <select class="form-control" name="assunto" required>   
                        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"> -- Escolha uma opção --</option>   
                        <option value="orcamento">Orçamentos</option>
                        <option value="compras">Departamento Compras</option>   
                        <option value="financeiro">Departamento Financerio</option>
                    </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Mensagem:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="mensagem" rows="6" id="mensagem" name="mensagem" placeholder="sua mensagem" required></textarea> 
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> 
                <input class = "btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="btnSend" type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
                <a name="formulario"></a>
                    <div class="mensagem-alerta"><?php echo $msg ?></div>
                </div> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    <footer>
        <hr>
          
    </footer>
```

parte PHP

```html
if (isset($_POST['btnSend'])) {

$msg = '';
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$mensagem = nl2br(str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $_POST['mensagem']));
$ipadress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date("d-m-Y"); 
$time = date("H:i:s"); 

if ((!empty($nome)) && (!empty($email)) && (!empty($telefone)) && (!empty($assunto)) && (!empty($mensagem))){


    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
    require "phpmailer/class.smtp.php"; //incluimos la clase para envíos por SMTP
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    
    $mail->From     = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $nome; 
    $mail->AddAddress("contato@visaomateriais.com.br"); //E-mail que receberá as mensagens.
   
// Dados que aparecerá no e-mail recebedor
            
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject  =  "Contato | Visao casa & construcao"; //Assunto E-mail
    $mail->Body     =  utf8_decode ("FORMULÁRIO DE CONTATO\n"
            . "<br><b>De:</b> " . $nome
            . "<br><b>Email:</b> " . $email
            . "<br><b>Telefone:</b> " . $telefone
            . "<br><b>Assunto:</b> " . $assunto
            . "<br><b>Mensagem:</b> " . $mensagem
            . "<br><br>"
            . "<hr>"
            . "<br>Mensagem enviada formulário www.visaomateriais.com.br"
            . "<br><b>Endereço IP do usuário:</b> ". $ipadress 
            . "<br><b>Data:</b> " . $date . " $time");
    

// Dados Servidor E-mail(SMTP)

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.titan.email"; //Servidor SMTP(de envio)
    $mail->Port = 465; //Porta Servidor E-mail
    $mail->Username = 'contato@visaomateriais.com.br';  // Usuário E-mail
    $mail->Password = 'Jtba1618*'; // Senha E-mail
    $mail->FromName = 'Contato | Visão casa & construção'; // Titulo E-mail
    $mail->From = 'contato@visaomateriais.com.br'; //E-mail Remetente(Evitar SPAM mesmo E-mail preenchido anteriormente)

        //valida se o email foi enviado
        if ($mail->Send()) {
            
            //mostra mensagem de envio com sucesso
            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <strong>Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</strong> 
            </div>';
        } else {

            //mostra mensagem de erro ao enviar
            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <strong>Erro ao enviar mensagem, tente novamente! </strong> 
            </div>';
        }
        
    } 
    else {
        
        //mostra mensagem de erro caso algum dos campos esteja vazio
        $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                <strong>Preencha todos os campos!! </strong> 
            </div>';
    }
}
```

Gostaria de uma Ajuda sou iniciante

Answer (score -2):

Isso significa que a variável $msg não está definida. Ela só está definida depois de submeter o formulário. Tens que definir a variável antes da condição if.

```
$msg = '';

if (isset($_POST['btnSend'])) {
```